# Inconsistent zoom levels for OpenLayers image and vector map layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

My OpenLayers map has 2 seperate layers, a TileLayer with a custom XYZ source and a VectorTileLayer with a custom VectorTile source:

```
var tileSource = new ThemedTileLayerSource({ url: this.props.url + "/GetThemedTile/{x}/{y}/{z}" }, this.props.theme);
var tileLayer = new TileLayer({ source: tileSource });

var labelSource = new LabelLayerSource({ url: this.props.url + "/GetLabels/{x}/{y}/{z}" }, this.props.theme, this.Map);
var labelLayer = new VectorTileLayer({ declutter:true, source: labelSource });

this.Map.addLayer(tileLayer);
this.Map.addLayer(labelLayer);
this.Map.setView(new View({ center: [2690583.3956,-3375459.1691], zoom: 5, minZoom: 5, maxZoom: 18, constrainResolution: true }));
this.Map.setTarget(this.MapDiv);
```

When the map initialises, even though `zoom` and `minZoom` on the view are set to 5, the vector tile layer requests tiles for zoom level 4 (the tile layer works correctly and requests tiles for zoom level 5). The vector tile layer will, from then on, consistently request tile data 1 zoom level below the tile layer each time the map is zoomed.

If I go ahead and attach `minZoom` and `maxZoom` properties to the sources:

```
var tileSource = new ThemedTileLayerSource({ url: this.props.url + "/GetThemedTile/{x}/{y}/{z}", minZoom:5, maxZoom: 18 }, this.props.theme);

var labelSource = new LabelLayerSource({ url: this.props.url + "/GetLabels/{x}/{y}/{z}", minZoom:5, maxZoom: 18 }, this.props.theme, this.Map);
```

Both layers start correctly and both request tiles for zoom level 5, but when zooming beyond zoom level 5, the vector tile layer once again remains 1 zoom layer behind the tile layer as it did without the min and max zooms set.

Interestingly, when zooming from level 5 to 6, the tile layer retrieves tiles for zoom level 6, but the vector layer does not request any new tiles at all. From then on, every time the map is zoomed the vector tile layer will request tiles for 1 zoom level below the tile layer.

Given that my max zoom on the view is set to 18, the issue with the vector tile layer means I can never retrieve the vector features beyond zoom level 17 for the vector tile layer.

Both the sources override the tileLoadFunction to make a simple XHR request to the server for the data they need and make no changes to the request URL:

```
tileLoadFunction = (tile, url) =>
{
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "json";
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    request.onload = function(e)
    {
        ...
    }

    request.send();
}
```

Does anybody know if this is a bug with OpenLayers or if I've just configured it incorrectly? And more importantly, how I can go about synching the zoom levels across the layers.

Comment: Vector tiles sources have a default tile size of 512px, tile sources have a default tile size of 256px, and at the same resolution a 512px grid is at one zoom level less than a 256px grid.

Comment: Ah! yeah that was it, I added `tileSize: 256` to the vector tile layer source properties and that fixed it, thanks. You can go ahead and add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.